# For VAT tax, what is the correct Decimal(p, s) precision and scale for SQL Server field size declaration?

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

I am defining VAT rates (European and other countries levy the VAT tax) in a SQL Server database and am wondering what the ideal decimal definition to capture the necessary precision.

I have seen [VAT rates](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=502578) of:

```
20% (0.20) UK, Italy, Austria, etc.
21% (0.21) Belgium, Ireland, etc. 
19.6% (0.196) Monaco, France
```

I am curious if there are cases where the VAT rate requires more precision than decimal(4, 3) where p is precision and s is scale.  I have read a number of documents and am not sure if the EU or others have a particular specification for the VAT in terms of positions after the "." (or "," in their case).  What's to stop the UK from saying their VAT is now 0.20111111 if they want to use some formula-based calculation for the VAT rate instead of a fixed-precision value?

Thanks in advance to you international men and women of mystery.

Comment: A couple of notes: the Decimal type defaults to decimal(18,0) per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: Oracle has a good glossary of terms surrounding the VAT: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/ar/impvat02.htm and http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/ar/impvat04.htm

Comment: For reference, I've noted in several other systems that values regarding currency, exchange, percentage (tariff rates) and other monetary-related values are stored at (19, 5) and (19, 7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PDF document referred at the end of [this page](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/taxation/vat/how_vat_works/rates/index_en.htm), you should be safe with `decimal(4,3)`. Although it seems that some historical cases would have required a precision of 4.

Comment: The `money` type can serve as an indirect evidence of the 'historical cases', having been prescribed the very precision of 4.

Comment: Being a stickler, I want to make sure that a precision of 4 won't leave any VAT percentages in truncation-land now, in the past or in the future.  Is there a definitive answer buried in the EU spec somewhere?  I have not found it yet despite searching.

Comment: The link does not exists anymore

Answer (score 0):

Being **nominal rates**, expected to be typed by millions of people a year, they are expected not to include more than one decimal digit (two at most).
This seems to be the case in Europe. Check these 2020 VAT tables to check the idea.

https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/sites/taxation/files/resources/documents/taxation/vat/how_vat_works/rates/vat_rates_en.pdf

https://taxsummaries.pwc.com/quick-charts/value-added-tax-vat-rates

https://www.avalara.com/vatlive/en/vat-rates/european-vat-rates.html

Beyond Europe Amazon keeps an empirical table that can be useful
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=502578